# Nesting async/await methods

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm writing a library that wraps a third party web service call and am trying to make the library use the new async/await features. What is the proper use of the async/await keywords in the following example?

```
public class MyApi
{
    public Task<ApiResult> DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        return this.DoSomethingCore();
    }

    public async Task<ApiResult> DoSomethingElseAsync()
    {
        return await this.DoSomethingCore();
    }

    private async Task<ApiResult> DoSomethingCore()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("some url");
        var rawResultText = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return new ApiResult(rawResultText);        
    }
}
```

To allow my caller to await the DoSomethingAsync method, should that method also have the async and await keywords added to it? Or is it fine as-is because it returns a Task? Is there a better pattern for this sort of nesting?

I think the DoSomethingAsync method is the correct way to go here, is that correct? I believe DoSomethingElseAsync seems the wrong approach when building a library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any `Task` can be awaited, regardless of where it came from.

I'm not sure why `DoSomethingAsync` just calls `DoSomethingCore`, since `DoSomethingAsync` could just as easily be `async` and use `await`.

There is also a [general rule](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library methods.

**Edit:** If you don't need to use `await`, then don't make the method `async`. `async` will add some overhead (check Channel9 for Stephen Toub's Zen of Async Performance video). If you can just return a `Task` (like `DoSomethingAsync`), then do it that way.

Comment: DoSomethingAsync calls DoSomethingCore because in my real-life scenario, I have two similar public methods that share functionality by using a core method. 

I will look into the ConfigureAwait method, as I had not seen that before.

Comment: I've added a DoSomethingElseAsync() method to better explain what I was confused about. I believe you have explained this sufficiently and that the DoSomethingAsync() method is the way to go for a library method.

Comment: @StephenCleary -- So, then should the signature be `public Task<ApiResult> DoSomethingElse()` and it just return `this.DoSomethingCore();`? Basically, since it's not `await`ing, it doesn't need to use the `async` keyword so he shouldn't need to name the method `DoSomethingElseAsync()`. Is this correct? This is clearly to clarify naming conventions and i know it's not syntactical.

Comment: @Sonic: The `Async` suffix is a convention that conveys it's designed to be *consumed* by `await`, not that it's *implemented* with `await`. So even if `DoSomethingElseAsync` doesn't use `async`/`await`, it should still use the `Async` suffix.

Answer (score 4):

The formulation below is functional, but will likely cause additional overhead (due to having a secondary callback for the additional async/await method.)

```
public async Task<ApiResult> DoSomethingElseAsync()
{
    return await this.DoSomethingCore();
}
```

It's simpler to return the Task directly, as you can always await that Task elsewhere without having to have the method implemented as 'async'.  Async/await is a lot like using 'yield return'; it does some compiler magic to implement the 'yielding', but the enumeration itself doesn't care how you implement it.  Likewise, an 'await' call doesn't care how the awaitable works, as long as it's awaitable.